# I am having trouble removing zeroes from unused operators

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

[image: .]

I wrote this spreadsheet in Google Sheets, and I am using an entire column to get the calculations of A+B=C. `ArrayFormula(E2:E*D2:D)` <-- this is for the entire C column's formula, but I need to modify it to not calculate if either A or B is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works

```
=ArrayFormula(if( len(E2:E) * len(D2:D); E2:E*D2:D;))
```

Comment: Perfect! You really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

use this formula instead:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(E2:E&D2:D), E2:E*D2:D, ))
```

[image]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(E2:E*D2:D&"", "^0", ))*1
```

[image: 0]

Comment: It works but I prefer an AND instead of an OR functionality.

Comment: @user10322453 alternative added